# C++ Pointer to const array of const pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I've created a const array of const pointers like so:

```
const char* const sessionList[] = {
    dataTable0,
    dataTable1,
    dataTable2,
    dataTable3
};
```

What is the correct syntax for a regular non-const pointer to this array? I thought it would be `const char**`, but the compiler thinks otherwise.

Comment: Technically, your `const char * *` would be equivalent to your array, since this is what your array will decay to when passed to a function. You'd need an extra indirection to get a pointer to the array. Or something like `const char * [] *`, but I'm not sure if that one is valid

Comment: It looks like the type of `&sessionList` is `const char * const (*)[4]`, but I'm struggling to declare a variable with such a type.

Comment: You shoud clarify whether you want a pointer to an array or a pointer to an element of an array. Those two are different things.

Comment: @KABoissonneault: The array decays to `const char * const *` when you use it in most contexts (everything except `sizeof`, `decltype` and `&`)

Comment: @ChrisDodd You're right, I was missing a `const`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
const char* const sessionList[] = { ... };
```

is better written as:

```
char const* const sessionList[] = { ... };
```

Type of `sessionList[0]` is `char const* const`.
Hence, type of `&sessionList[0]` is `char const* const*`.

You can use:

```
char const* const* ptr = &sessionList[0];
```

or

```
char const* const* ptr = sessionList;
```

That declares a pointer to the elements of `sessionList`. If you want to declare a pointer to the entire array, it needs to be:

```
char const* const (*ptr)[4] = &sessionList;
```

Answer (score 6):

If you actually need a pointer to an array, as your title suggests, then this is the syntax:

```
const char* const (*ptr)[4] = &sessionList;
```

Answer (score 2):

The same type as you declared for the array elements, with an extra `*` added:

```
const char* const *
```

Comment: @juanchopanza: That's a pointer type that can point at any element of the array, which is *usually* what people mean by the term 'pointer to the array' -- the pointer type that the array name turns into when you use it.